# How to store extra quantities in recursive calls

Tags: python, recursion

Consider the following recursive python code that computes some minimum

```
global d

def f1(a,b):
   if b<=0:
      return 0
   if a<=0:
      return 99999
   return 1+f1(a-(b-a),b-a)

def f2(a,b,c):
   if a<=0:
      return 99999
   if c<=0:
      return f1(a,b-d)
   minimum = 99999
   for i in range(a):
       if i>c:
          break
       minimum = min(minimum,1+f2(a-(b-i),b-i+d,c-(a-i)))
   return minimum

def f3(a,b,c):
   global d
   d = c
   ret = f2(a,0,b)
   return ret
```

I would like to change it so that it returns not just the minimum but also the quantities `a-(b-i)`, `b-i+d` and `c-(a-i)` in the `i` loop of `f2` that produced that minimum.

The more obvious way would be to use a dictionary where the keys are

```
1+f2(a-(b-i), b-i+d, c-(a-i))
```

and the values would be

```
a-(b-i), b-i+d, c-(a-i)
```

and then I could find the smallest key value and its value.
But not sure how to build the dictionary as the recursive calls are made.

Comment: You know that `return 1,2` will return the tuple `(1, 2)` right? And that you can unpack t-uples into t variables at once…

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your code, as it seems to be a bit bloated. For example, `f1()` looks like it just checks which passed value is smaller, which could be one-lined without any recursion with `return 0 if b<a else 99999`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it's not which one is smaller. It returns a constant if either one is negative or else it recurse.

Comment: @JohnColeman - `a - (b - a)` is equivalent to `2*a - b`, not `b`. `b` would be equivalent to `a - (a - b)`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Of course. I mentally overlooked the parenthesis and didn't distribute.

Comment: This code could really use some docstrings/comments.

Comment: Also, in `f2`, the `if i>c: break` can be eliminated with a `for i in range(min(a,c))`

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite `f2` to achieve you desired result:

```
def f2(a,b,c):
    if a<=0:
        return 99999
    if c<=0:
        return f1(a,b-d)
    minimum = 99999
    max_iter = min(a,c)
    for i in range(max_iter):
        # replace *_ with qty1, qt2, qty3 if you want to do something with the returned values at this stage
        mini, *_ = f2(a-(b-i),b-i+d,c-(a-i))
        minimum = min(minimum, 1 + mini)
    return minimum, a - b + max_iter, b - max_iter + d, c - a + max_iter
```

You might also want to adapt `f3` accordingly.